# обернуть блоки в ссылку

Tags: html, css3

есть блок

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link-news">
      <img src="assets/img/news1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="box-info">
        <h3><a href="">Скоро отпуск!</a></h3>
        <span>05.08.2017</span>
        <p class="description">
          Все мы люди и иногда нам требуется перезагрузка. На этот раз мы запланировали отпуск чуть больше обычного. Нас не будет ....
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

.news .item {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
.news .item .link-news {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

как обернуть в ссылку картинку и блок box-info?
в данный момент у меня в браузере вот так? в ссылку оборачивается только картинка и еще добавляются такие ссылки

```
<div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="link-news">
          <img src="assets/img/news1.jpg" alt="">
          </a><div class="box-info"><a href="#" class="link-news">
            </a><h3><a href="#" class="link-news"></a><a href="">Скоро отпуск!</a></h3>
            <span>05.08.2017</span>
            <p class="description">
              Все мы люди и иногда нам требуется перезагрузка. На этот раз мы запланировали отпуск чуть больше обычного.
Нас не будет ....
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: предположу, что у вас какая-то cms и встроенный редактор html не правильно настроен.

Comment: sublime text  =  bootstrap+less

Comment: @SergeyNovikov, с чего такие выводы? В ссылки нельзя вставлять блочные элементы, откройте просто консоль и посмотрите что получается, даже если задать ссылке `display: block;`

Comment: @HamSter большое спасибо за ответ, но автор уже все написал

Comment: @HamSter нельзя вставлять блочные элементы в ссылки? Можно по-подробнее?

Comment: @Cheg, возьмите сами почитайте о строчных и блочных элементах. Да нельзя, если придерживаться валидности кода, а если нет, то пожалуйста.

Comment: @HamSter w3 validator не выдаст ни одной ошибки, если вставить `div` в `a`

Comment: Зачем вам обернуть класс в сылку ? может вам это нужно ?
`<div class="link-news" href="Home">
          <img src="assets/img/news1.jpg" alt=""></div>`

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```css
.item {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
  
  position: relative;
}

.item .link-news {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
    <div class="box-info">
      <h3><a href="">Скоро отпуск!</a></h3>
      <span>05.08.2017</span>
      <p class="description">
        Все мы люди и иногда нам требуется перезагрузка. На этот раз мы запланировали отпуск чуть больше обычного. Нас не будет ....
      </p> 
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="link-news"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```